# Distributing a C command line tool in a OS X .app Bundle

Tags: c, command-line, app-bundle

I wrote a C command line tool which uses [GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit) to visualize a genetic algorithm and I want to distribute it in a Mac OS X .app Bundle.

How do I do that? Are there any helper tools available for this?

Thank you very much!
Thomas

Edit:
Thank you very much for your help, I didn't think of it being that easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new xcode project, with "application" template. Add your source code to that project, compile and... You have app bundle. You need only to deploy it (add frameworks). Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile your code, you can use the Mac OS X IDE XCode.
If you want an installer for that, you can use the Package Maker.

> (I have already found the Package
>   Maker utility - but that is not what I
>   wanted.)

Package Maker is for distribution. May I know why package maker won't help?

Comment: Compiling is no problem, the program itself already works well. As it is a (relatively) small programm I don't want the users to install it but just drag and drop it into their applications folder. It needs some images and I thought it was nice to have a all-in-one Application Bundle for that.

Comment: Oh i see...Now I understand what you want to achieve. You want an image from your "compiled" code (perhaps an icon). And you want to create an all-in-one bundle for that. The solution is simple. Just open XCode and create a new project (choose Cocoa). Paste your code, compile it, and you got a .app extension. This will be your bundle. This is already executable. From there, you can also change it's icon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must link the library into the bundle in order to avoid issue.
Look the issue about Universal build instead of doing a PPC and Intel build.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I misread something - but I don't know how this is about to help. The program is already compiling and I have the executable - all I want to do is to have this in a .app container with an icon and all the images needed.

Comment: I used to make the wormux release but it was years ago. The bundle part seems looking good : http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/whatismacosx//programming.html