# How to use 'SQLite' (the wrapper on github) in a Command Line Tool?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift, sqlite.swift

I'm successfully using the great Swift wrapper for sqlite from https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift in a **Cocoa application**.

But when I try to use the wrapper in a **Command Line Tool project** and follow the same detailed installation steps I get the following error:

> Check dependencies
>
> Unable to run command 'PBXCp SQLite.framework' - this target might
>   include its own product.

I checked the dependencies, but couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link dynamic framework (a .framework) with your app in a Command Line Tool project. The reason is simple — a command line tool target builds a single binary file. This is unlike a regular Cocoa application, where the `.app` "file" is actually a folder containing `.framework`s and other stuff inside.

So basically you'd have to build a static library instead (one that links with your app's binary during compilation) — except that as of Xcode 6.1 [it's not possible yet with Swift](https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#static-libraries).

So the only thing you can do — AFAIK — is add the SQLite.swift's source code directly into your own app target (so it compiles together). It's ugly, but works.

Comment: There is another question regarding the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630911/using-frameworks-in-a-command-line-tool