# The simplest way to import a framework into a command line target

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line

What is the simplest way to import code into a command line target ? Ideally, a bundle, such as the [PrettyColors](https://github.com/jdhealy/PrettyColors) framework, for instance.

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630911/using-frameworks-in-a-command-line-tool) was asked 7 years ago and I was hoping Apple have since made some improvements.

EDIT: What I mean by command line target is an XCode command line tool executable template...

[image]

Comment: You could use the Swift Package Manager.

Comment: Oh really @Palle ? Any special steps required for command line targets ?

Comment: No, just create your project with `swift package init --type executable` and then add your dependencies to the Package.swift file. You can also generate an Xcode Project using `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Comment: If the Swift Package Manager does work, why not use it? Otherwise you still need to follow the instructions from the answer to the original question.

Comment: @Palle I want the IDE environment

Comment: Then use `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and you have your Xcode project.

Comment: @Palle no way! very cool.