# MacOS - How to deploy C++ application

Tags: c++, macos, deployment

I'm having really hard time figuring out, how to deploy C++ application in macOS. By deploying I mean a package which contains frameworks, resources and an unix executable so anyone who downloads my app will be able to run it without any further configuration.
Thanks in advance for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

One solution should be to download Xcode from the appStore (free) : all needed tools to build an application bundle, a command line tool, a framework or a library are available in the software.

When building an application having a user interface, some codes in objective-c or swift are required at some point to communicate with the Cocoa frameworks, but for a command line tool it could be pure C/C++. Here is a link to a [tutorial](https://jtdaugh.github.io/xcode-umich/) about that specific case.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response. I didn't find any tips on how to deploy an application in Xcode. I only found how to start a project and basic stuff...

Comment: An application is produced at any time you build the target. But there are generally several versions (schemes), for instance one for debugging and one for release (production). Release versions are generally finalized by archiving them which give you a sharable product. All these features are available from Xcode using the scheme editor and the target build settings. Here is another link that may be interesting for you about some specific aspect of deploying a command line tool on the last macOS versions (>= Catalina) : https://scriptingosx.com/2019/09/notarize-a-command-line-tool/

Comment: It's very interesting reading indeed but I'm afraid that it won't solve my problem as I'm trying to export my project, not to notarize it. Basically I can do Product->Archive which will export my application but I still do have a problem with dyld. I just need to somehow include frameworks folder into my exported archive but I don't have a clue how.

Comment: You might find some useful info about that here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630911/using-frameworks-in-a-command-line-tool